# Unable to load CSS and Javascript Property in Web Browser while running the asp.net mvc web app in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I am unable to load CSS property while running the asp.net mvc web application developed using visual studio 2019. I used a layout page(_Layout1.cshtml) and created a view "Index" which inherits the layout page. In the layout page I have used html footer and header.

I tried specifying path to the css and js files present under myContent folder created by  me using "@Url.Content" property. I am not getting any error and I am able to see only the texts in the browser but css not loading. Please find the screenshots for better understanding.

I am getting only contents only but not getting CSS and js property in browser: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGYLS.png)

This is some part of my html code under head tag in cshtml file:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<title>Destino</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="Destino project">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=@Url.Content("/myContent/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css")>
</head>
```

Comment: This is some part of my html code under head tag in cshtml file:
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <title>Destino</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Destino project">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
     href=@Url.Content("/myContent/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css")>
    </head>

Comment: Try to give full directory path of your css, js instead of any relative path. This way you can easily load css/js.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The issue is now resolved.